# How to preload image from url in splash screen?

Tags: android, firebase, picasso

I have a chat app and I want to load users profile image when user is in splash screen.actually I want initialize everything but splash screen hide this for 1 second.But images loading when splash ended like without splash screen.

I am using recyclerview and taking datas on firebase.When opening ,pictures comes little bit after.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

 ...
        viewHolder.nickname.setText(odialog.getNickname());

        Picasso.get()
                .load(odialog.getProfil_pic())
                .centerCrop()
                .fit()
                .noFade()

                .into(viewHolder.profile_image);
...
```

Splash activity.

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.SplashTheme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app dashboard activity
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, 2000);
```

I find the solution[splash with dialog][1]
https://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right/

Comment: What's the actual problem? Please be specific.

Comment: I want to load activity on background  and user wait until everything done . but images doesn't loading on splash screen. they loads when main activity start. and image comes slowly. i want to all images prepared when main activity seen.

Comment: And what's wrong with the shared code?

Comment: it loads late but i  changed all code. splash screen broke the main theme i cant use it